# Is it possible to get a response from event fired through Akka Event Stream (scala)?

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

In are app, we are quite heavily using Akka Event Stream to handle logic that is not related to the main business flow. Things like: send emails, sync records, etc... All of these events are currently fired and forgotten.

```
system.eventStream.publish(<event>)
```

And they are handled by listeners, asynchronously, in most cases.
However, I am now investigating an option of extending class functionality through events system and that, sometimes, requires a return value from an event? 
Is it even possible to get some result back from an event? I could not find anything specific in this regard.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It's a feature of event based systems: you know who triggered the event, you don't know who will handle it, nor when (can be asynchronous).

So, the most idiomatic solution, if your listener should generate an answer, is to do it in an asynchronous way. And as such, the listener should send an event with it's answer.

Another way to do it is to bypass the event bus and register you handlers as listeners of your event source (you should handle your self the registe/unregister functions through akka messages and a simple list). And when your event source triggers the listeners, it can do it using the ask pattern.